# Google Chrome Extension getting sub attribute title from LINK

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I've developed an extension based on the downloader which basically downloads multiple links from a web page.

I have a popup (popup.html and popup.js) which shows all the full links in the page which I want to download with the checkbox:

```
https://home/user/testing/DSDSDSDSSFTTTTHHFJYJYJY
https://home/user/testing/DSDSDSDSSFTTTTH54JYJYJY
https://home/user/testing/DSDSDSDSSFTTTTH76JYJYJY
https://home/user/testing/DSDSDSDSSFTTTTH87JYJYJY
```

the problem I'm facing is that I haven't been able to get the "title" property from the  tag to display the FILENAME instead of the FULL URL.

my current code is:

popup.js

```
// This extension demonstrates using chrome.downloads.download() to
// download URLs.

var allLinks = [];
var visibleLinks = [];

// Display all visible links.
// Display all visible links.
function showLinks() {
  var linksTable = document.getElementById('links');
  while (linksTable.children.length > 1) {
    linksTable.removeChild(linksTable.children[linksTable.children.length - 1])
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < visibleLinks.length; ++i) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var col0 = document.createElement('td');
    var col1 = document.createElement('td');
    var col2 = document.createElement('td');

    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.checked = true;
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.id = 'check' + i;
    col0.appendChild(checkbox);


    //display only the href title
    //col2.innerText = "---text---";
    col2.innerText = visibleLinks[i].getAttribute("title"); //<-----ERROR
    //Error in event handler: TypeError: visibleLinks[i].getAttribute is not a function

    //display the full URL
    col1.innerText = visibleLinks[i];
    col1.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';



    col1.onclick = function() {
      checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
    }
    row.appendChild(col0);
    row.appendChild(col1);
    row.appendChild(col2);
    linksTable.appendChild(row);
  }
}


// Toggle the checked state of all visible links.
function toggleAll() {
  var checked = document.getElementById('toggle_all').checked;
  for (var i = 0; i < visibleLinks.length; ++i) {
    document.getElementById('check' + i).checked = checked;
  }
}

// Download all visible checked links.
function downloadCheckedLinks() {
  for (var i = 0; i < visibleLinks.length; ++i) {
    if (document.getElementById('check' + i).checked) 
    {
      chrome.downloads.download({url: visibleLinks[i]},
        function(id) {
      });
    }
    //window.close();
  }
}

// Re-filter allLinks into visibleLinks and reshow visibleLinks.
function filterLinks() {
  var filterValue = document.getElementById('filter').value;
  if (document.getElementById('regex').checked) {
    visibleLinks = allLinks.filter(function(link) {
      return link.match(filterValue);
    });
  } else {
    var terms = filterValue.split(' ');
    visibleLinks = allLinks.filter(function(link) {
      for (var termI = 0; termI < terms.length; ++termI) {
        var term = terms[termI];
        if (term.length != 0) {
          var expected = (term[0] != '-');
          if (!expected) {
            term = term.substr(1);
            if (term.length == 0) {
              continue;
            }
          }
          var found = (-1 !== link.indexOf(term));
          if (found != expected) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
    });
  }
  showLinks();
}

// Add links to allLinks and visibleLinks, sort and show them.  send_links.js is
// injected into all frames of the active tab, so this listener may be called
// multiple times.
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(links) {
  for (var index in links) {
    allLinks.push(links[index]);
  }
  allLinks.sort();
  visibleLinks = allLinks;
  showLinks();
});

// Set up event handlers and inject send_links.js into all frames in the active
// tab.
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('filter').onkeyup = filterLinks;
  document.getElementById('regex').onchange = filterLinks;
  document.getElementById('toggle_all').onchange = toggleAll;
  document.getElementById('download0').onclick = downloadCheckedLinks;
  document.getElementById('download1').onclick = downloadCheckedLinks;

  chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (currentWindow) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: currentWindow.id},
                      function(activeTabs) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        activeTabs[0].id, {file: 'send_links.js', allFrames: true});
    });
  });
};
```

send_links.js

```
// Copyright (c) 2012 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// Send back to the popup a sorted deduped list of valid link URLs on this page.
// The popup injects this script into all frames in the active tab.

var links = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
links = links.map(function(element) {
  // Return an anchor's href attribute, stripping any URL fragment (hash '#').
  // If the html specifies a relative path, chrome converts it to an absolute
  // URL.
  var href = element.href;
  var hashIndex = href.indexOf('#');
  if (hashIndex >= 0) {
    href = href.substr(0, hashIndex);
  }

  console.log(element);

  return href;
});

links.sort();

// Remove duplicates and invalid URLs.
var kBadPrefix = 'javascript';
for (var i = 0; i < links.length;) {
  if (((i > 0) && (links[i] == links[i - 1])) ||
      (links[i] == '') ||
      (kBadPrefix == links[i].toLowerCase().substr(0, kBadPrefix.length))) {
    links.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    ++i;
  }
}

chrome.extension.sendRequest(links);
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src='popup.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type=text id=filter placeholder=Filter>
<input type=checkbox id=regex>
<label for=regex>Regex</label><br>
<table id=links>
  <tr>
    <th><input type=checkbox checked id=toggle_all></th>
    <th align=left>URL</th>
    <th align=left>test</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id=download1>Download</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically I'm asking how should I go about getting the title from the link in the line where it says "ERROR".

any suggestions?

Comment: Where is `visibleLinks` defined/set?

Comment: I've edited the post adding the variable definition, basically they are defined as global var as an array in popup.js thanks for looking into it.

Comment: `visibleLinks` is never set in the code shown

Comment: it's line 5. refresh the page maybe that's why you dont see it.

Comment: `var visibleLinks = [];` just sets `visibleLinks` as an empty array.

Comment: my bad. I've added all the functions, as I understand the links are being grabbed in send_links.js and then that function is called in popup.js . I appreciate your guidance.